# I'm trying to write a class that stores an array list and has multiple methods

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have to write a program that interacts with the user and to add and review airline reservations. I'm writing this class here call `ReservationSystem` and I need to create the following methods:
`addReservation()` that takes as input first name, last name, price, seat number, and seat letter and creates a Reservation with this info, then I need to add the reservation to the list of reservations. Next I need to create another `addReservation()` method that prompts the user for the info needed to make a new reservation and add this reservation to the list of reservations. Next I need to create a method `viewReservations()` that prints all reservations using `System.out` and I have to use my `toString()` method provided by `Reservation` class. For some reason it's not seeing my `String firstName` variable as a 
String in my `viewReservations()` method. Also how do I combine all my inputs into one variable, in this code I've just been using `+` to combine the inputs, not sure if that's correct.

```
ReservationSystem class:

package finalproject;
import java.util.*;

public class ReservationSystem {

ArrayList<String> reservations = new ArrayList<>();


public String addReservation(String firstName, String lastName, String 
price, String seatNumber, String seatLetter){

    String reservation = firstName + lastName + price + seatNumber + 
seatLetter;
    reservations.add(reservation);

    return reservation;
}

public void addReservation(){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter new reservation: ");
    String reservation = s.nextLine();

    reservations.add(reservation);
}

public void viewReservation(){

    Reservation res = new Reservation(String firstName, String lastName, 
String price, String seatNumber, String seatLetter);

    res.toString(firstName, lastName, String, seatNumber, seatNumber);
}




}
```

Reservation Class:

```
package finalproject;

public class Reservation {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String price;
private String seatNumber;
private String seatLetter;

public Reservation(String firstName, String lastName){

this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
}   

/**
 *
 * @param price
 */
public Reservation(String price){

this.price = price;
}

public Reservation(String seatNumber){

this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
}

public Reservation(String seatLetter){

this.seatLetter = seatLetter;
}

/**
 *
 * @param firstName
 * @param lastName
 * @param price
 * @param seatNumber
 * @param seatLetter
 * @return
 */
public String toString(String firstName, String lastName, String price, 
String seatNumber, String seatLetter){

String info = firstName + lastName + price + seatNumber + seatLetter;
return info;

} 

/**
 *
 * @param price
 * @return
 */
public String getPrice(String price){

return price;
}

}
```

Comment: You should have a `List<Reservation>` instead of `ArrayList<String>` and add the `Reservation` objects, which need to have a constructor that takes all the parameters (the code here won't even compile). The `toString()` shouldn't take any parameters; it should assemble the result from the fields. It's fine to concatenate them with `+` but you probably want to put spaces between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reservation class**

```
public class Reservation {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private float price;
    private int seatNumber;
    private char seatLetter;

    // Constructor. Aligns values to the fields.
    public Reservation(String firstName, String lastName,
            float price, int seatNumber, char seatLetter){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.price = price;
        this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
        this.seatLetter = seatLetter;
    }

    // Returns a string with the values of the fields.
    public String toString(){
        return firstName + " " + lastName
            + "\nPrice: " + price
            + "\nSeat: " + seatLetter + seatNumber;
    }

    // Returns the value of seatLetter
    public char getSeatLetter() {
        return seatLetter;
    }
    // Returns the value of seatNumber
    public int getSeatNumber() {
        return seatNumber;
    }
}
```

**ReservationSystem class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReservationSystem {

    List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();

    //Adds a Reservation object to the list
    public void addReservation(Reservation reservation){
        reservations.add(reservation);
    }
    // Prints a Reservation from the list based on seat number and seat letter
    public void viewReservation(int seatNumber, char seatLetter){
        for(Reservation res : reservations){
            // if seat number and seat letter dont match continue to the next reservation
            if(res.getSeatNumber() != seatNumber && res.getSeatLetter() != seatLetter){ continue; }
                System.out.println(res.toString());
            return;
        }
}
    // Prints all the Reservation objects of the list
    public void viewAllReservations(){
        for(Reservation res : reservations){
            System.out.println(res.toString() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**in your Main class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReservationSystem resSystem = new ReservationSystem();
    //Getting the values for a new reservation from user
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
    String firstName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
    String lastName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Price: ");
    float price = sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter Seat Number: ");
    int seatNumber = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Seat Letter: ");
    char seatLetter = sc.next().charAt(0);
    sc.close();
    // Adding new reservation object to the list
    resSystem.addReservation(new Reservation(firstName, lastName, price, seatNumber, seatLetter));

    // Printing All the reservations from the list
    resSystem.viewAllReservations();
}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining what you have done in words. Just dumping some code isn’t very helpful